# Create a List with varied length in the for loop

Tags: r

I would like to create a `List` that is going to vary everytimes `for loop` runs. Actually, the new `list` length is depend on the length of the existing `List`. Following is small part of my large code:

```
for (i in 1:length(df1$x)) {
   for (j in 1:length(df2$y[[i]])) {

     if (df1$x[i] == df2$y[[i]][j]) {

     }

   }
}
```

In the code, `df2$y` is my list and my second `for loop` length is based on length of my `df2$y` list. Basically, I am accessing an element in `df2$y` list and comparing with `df1$x`. So, `If condition` met then I would like to save that list element into the newly created list. Length of the list is large. So, many list elements are going to meet the condition. Hence, I need to create a new list in the `for loop`.

Comment: If you described the problem fully, I have a feeling someone might be able to help you out with a much more elegant solution which doesn't involve nested control flows.

Comment: My code is bit complex and I have another for loop inside it. I tried to keep my question as simple as I can to get the proper answer to the problem I am facing. I am facing a problem in creating a new list in the for loop. About the nested control flows, I know it's unnecessary which can be simplified by using `foreach`.

Comment: Just keep a counter,n, of the current length of the output list and add elements to the list at position n+1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for all your comments. So, I solved my problem by myself which I realized was trivial. In my answer, I created a new list `newList` initially with fixed which I know is important as a preallocation of memory to reduce the computation time. Then I saved the new element into the `newList` using `[[]][]` when `if condition` met. Following is my approach which worked well for me:

```
newList <- vector("list", N)
for (i in 1:length(df1$x)) {
   for (j in 1:length(df2$y[[i]])) {

     if (df1$x[i] == df2$y[[i]][j]) {

        newList[[i]][j] <- df2$z[j]

     }

  }
}
```

Note: I answered my question by myself because I would like to inform that my problem is solved. I really appreciate all your opinion and help.

Answer (score 0):

I am a little confused but I think you are trying to create a new list of every element in `df2$y` that is in `df1$x`. If that is the case you can take of advantage of vectorized code:

```
df1 <- list(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10)
df2 <- list(5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 5, 5, 7, 8, 10, 22, 23, 4, 5, 3, 10)

#Create a list with 15 elements
df3 <- y[y %in% x]
```

Comment: My `df1$x` is not the list. What I am doing in the `if` originally is not just comparing but fuzzy matching of string.

Comment: @user3669801 could you put the fact you are fuzzy matching and some details about how in the question?

Comment: @user3669801 Also is the final output you are looking for the length of the number of matching elements in `df1$x` or the number of matched elements in `df2$y`?

Comment: I solved the problem by myself yesterday. Thanks for comments. I created a new list `newList <- vector("list", N)` and then saved the list element into the `newList` when `if condition` met. To saved the element of list into the `newList`, I used `newList[[i]][j] <- df2$z[j]`. It did exactly I wanted.